# XML Parsing Error "well-formed"

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have XML data in data base (not file)
i need to parse it to gave possibility write test to verify data in xml

xml (content data):

```
 <brid:AccountData xmlns:brid="http://billing.a1telekom.at/BridgeIT/BridgeITDefinition">
 <brid:AccountNumber>250000000032</brid:AccountNumber>
 <brid:CustomerNumber>100104653</brid:CustomerNumber>
 <brid:AccountType>NORM</brid:AccountType>
 <brid:BillCycle>M2</brid:BillCycle>
 <brid:LastInvoiceDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00.000</brid:LastInvoiceDate>
 <brid:BillThroughDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00.000</brid:BillThroughDate>
 <brid:StartDate>2016-02-26T15:27:13</brid:StartDate>
 <brid:EndDate>9999-12-31T23:59:59.000</brid:EndDate>
 <brid:AccountStatus>Active</brid:AccountStatus>
 <brid:TaxCode>U2</brid:TaxCode>
 <brid:CostCentre></brid:CostCentre>
</brid:AccountData>
<brid:PaymentData xmlns:brid="http://billing.a1telekom.at/BridgeIT/BridgeITDefinition">
 <brid:PaymentMethod>Manual</brid:PaymentMethod>
</brid:PaymentData>
<brid:MediaData xmlns:brid="http://billing.a1telekom.at/BridgeIT/BridgeITDefinition">
 <brid:AccountNumber>250000000032</brid:AccountNumber>
 <brid:MediaType>PAPIER</brid:MediaType>
 <brid:StartDate>2016-02-26T15:27:13</brid:StartDate>
 <brid:EndDate>9999-12-31T23:59:59.000</brid:EndDate>
 <brid:InvoiceName>ApuiafgjkLrjgdna Fouydf</brid:InvoiceName>
 <brid:Language>DE</brid:Language>
 <brid:LocationID>118298</brid:LocationID>
 <brid:FirstName>Fouydf</brid:FirstName>
 <brid:LastName>ApuiafgjkLrjgdna</brid:LastName>
 <brid:TitleCode></brid:TitleCode>
 <brid:TitleText></brid:TitleText>
 <brid:Prefix></brid:Prefix>
 <brid:Suffix>Cxvb</brid:Suffix>
 <brid:Currency>EUR</brid:Currency>
 <brid:Format>2</brid:Format>
 <brid:Atomized>N</brid:Atomized>
</brid:MediaData>
```

How i try to parse it:

p

```
ackage simbaOnlineReplacement;

import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import ta.maxcare.help.DBSor;




public class XMLTest2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String data = new DBSor().getContentData("106897066");

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(data));
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("MediaData");
            System.out.println("----------------------------");
            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                    System.out.println("First Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("FirstName").item(0).getTextContent());

                    System.out.println("LastName : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("LastName").item(0).getTextContent());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and e given error:

> [Fatal Error] :14:2: The markup in the document following the root
>   element must be well-formed. org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 2; The markup in the document following
>   the root element must be well-formed.     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at simbaOnlineReplacement.XMLTest2.main(XMLTest2.java:23)

Comment: Is the above sample xml document complete? It doesn't have a root node?

Comment: this is complete and working xml data,
as i said before, it is not a file, it is data in our database

Answer (score 1):

In well formed XML, you must have **one** root element. `brid:AccountData`, `brid:PaymentData` and `brid:MediaData` are at the same level, and this is wrong. You should have a root element enclosing them all, as an example.

Comment: If the input data really does not have a single root element, you can probably fix it by just wrapping it all in `<xml> ... </xml>`.

Comment: XML is not editable, it sends to other system. It is not wrong.
i need just verify name and last name

Comment: @user3898998: I see, but the parsing method expects a well formed document. I think you should read that document from DB, save it locally making it a well-formed one, and then operate on the local one. Maybe following Thilo's advice could help you.

Comment: If you know what to expect and not well-formed then parse it as text. Alternatively, use HTML parser. It will do it best to parse unformed xml. Try JSoup.

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is a well-formed external general parsed entity, but it is not a well-formed document. The easiest way to handle it is therefore to create a simple wrapper file that references it as an external entity:

```
<!DOCTYPE wrapper [
<!ENTITY e SYSTEM "data.xml">
]>
<wrapper>&e;</wrapper>
```

and then parse the wrapper file.